# Rails Eager loading has_many associations for an existing object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am fairly new to rails & I am having this performance issue that I would appreciate any help with.

I have a User model & each user has_many UserScores associated. I am preparing a dashboard showing different user stats including counts of user_scores based on certain conditions. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
def dashboard
@users = Array.new
users = User.order('created_at ASC')
users.each do |u|
    user = {}
    user[:id] = u.id
    user[:name] = u.nickname
    user[:email] = u.email
    user[:matches] = u.user_scores.count
    user[:jokers_used] = u.user_scores.where(:joker => true).length
    user[:jokers] = u.joker
    user[:bonus] = u.user_scores.where(:bonus => 1).length
  user[:joined] = u.created_at.strftime("%y/%m/%d")
    if user[:matches] > 0
        user[:last_activity] = u.user_scores.order('updated_at DESC').first.updated_at.strftime("%y/%m/%d")
    else
        user[:last_activity] = u.updated_at.strftime("%y/%m/%d")
    end
    @users << user
end
@user_count = @users.count
```

end

The issue I am seeing is repeated UserScore db queries for each user to get the different counts.

Is there a way to avoid those multiple queries??

N.B. I'm not sure if my approach for preparing data for the view is the optimal way, so any advice or tips regarding that will be greatly appreciated as well.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, reference `user_scores` association in your query:

```
users = User.includes(:user_scores).order('created_at ASC')
```

Follow rails documentation associations eager loading: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Also note that `where` makes new query to the database even if your association is already preloaded. Therefore, instead of

```
u.user_scores.where(:joker => true).length
u.user_scores.where(:bonus => 1).length
```

try:

```
u.user_scores.count { |us| us.joker }
u.user_scores.count { |us| us.bonus == 1 }
```

You will probably have to rewrite `.user_scores.order('updated_at DESC').first.updated_at.strftime("%y/%m/%d")` somehow as well

Comment: I tried that, but still the multiple queries for user_scores were happening for each user

Comment: Because `where` makes new query to database even if your association is already preloaded. Instead of

`u.user_scores.where(:joker => true).length`
and `u.user_scores.where(:bonus => 1).length`

try:

`u.user_scores.any? { |us| us.joker }`
and `u.user_scores.any? { |us| us.bonus == 1 }`

You will probably have to rewrite `.user_scores.order('updated_at DESC').first.updated_at.strftime("%y/%m/%d")` somehow as well

Comment: tried it & giving me this error 
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Comment: With your edit the multiple queries are not happening but i am not getting a count; just a value of the field (true or false)

Comment: @PeterB Ah, sorry. If you need size then instead of `.any?` you can try `.count` with same block

Comment: Thx makes sense

Answer (score 2):

You need to eager load users_scores to reduce multiple queries. @Slava.K provided good explanation on how to eliminate that.
Add `includes(:user_scores)` for querying users, and use ruby's methods to work with collections once data is fetched from DB through query.

See code below to understand that:

```
users = User.includes(:user_scores).order('created_at ASC')

users.each do |u|
  ....

  user[:matches] = u.user_scores.length
  user[:jokers_used] = u.user_scopes.select{ |score|  score.joker == true }.length
  user[:jokers] = u.joker
  user[:bonus] = u.user_scores.select{ |score|  score.bonus == 1 }.length
  ....
end
```

Also, The way you are preparing response is not clean and flexible. Instead you should override `as_json` method to prepare json which can consumed by views properly.  `as_json` method is defined for models by default. You can read more about it from official documentation http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html or visit [article on preparing clean json response](http://parthtalks.weebly.com/blog/preparing-clean-and-customized-json-response-for-rails-api) where I explained about overriding as_json properly in-depth.

Comment: Can you please add a reference how to use a JSON response with an HTML view?

Comment: as_json will return hash, which can be used to prepare response or can be used as variable as you used in your question.

Comment: so pass the hash as a local to the html view?

Answer (score 1):

Use includes method for eager loading your has many associations. You can understand this concept here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2EPVMqOsTQ